# Replace part of a column's text with encrypted value

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2016

Using `EncryptByKey`, can I replace just a portion of a `varchar(max)` column's text with an encrypted value? I attempted

```
replace( data, matched_string, EncryptByKey( Key_GUID( 'encKey' ), matched_string) ) as new_string
```

but it seems to have concatenated the string. Further, I'm not sure if there's a "good" way to decrypt just that portion of the string.

Comment: No. You could, however, store that value in a different column and use a place holder in the CLOB.

Comment: I figured this would be the answer, since it's varbinary data.

Comment: The only reason I've ever heard to want to do this was as part of a ransomware attack, where encrypting only the first 4Kb (one disk block read) of most files is enough to effectively render them worthless until decrypted, and allows the attacker to get through more the disk faster before A/V software might intervene

Comment: Or you could convert the encryted data to `varchar` as hex, and store it like that, but it would take up more space